# How do I deploy a Nuxtjs static site to Hostgator or another shard hosting provider?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, static, nuxt.js, hosting

Is there a way to deploy a Nuxtjs static site to a shared hosting provider like hostgator? I thought uploading the dist folder and pointing to the index.html file would be enough but looks like you need to keep the app live using `nuxt start`?

It's only working for me when I run `nuxt start` when testing locally, but not sure how you would keep that live on the server. I want to be able integrate with git for continuous development/deployment as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: that should be enough `npm run generate` and upload your files inside the dist folder to your webserver

Answer (score 0):

if you build for `static` you just need to upload `/dist` content

nuxt.config.js

```
target: 'static',
```

terminal: `nuxt generate`